# What allows certain polygons (not necessarily regular) to tessellate?

Tags: geometry, tessellations

There are irregular pentagons that tessellate. Is there some observable property?

[image: Known irregular pentagons that tessellate, by year]

Please provide anything else you want to relative to the question, thank you!

Comment: If any "observable property" were easy to articulate, then it *probably* would not have taken almost a century to find 15 cases, nor thirty years to get from #14 to #15. ;)  By the way, [here's a non-technical Guardian article about the new discovery](http://www.theguardian.com/science/alexs-adventures-in-numberland/2015/aug/10/attack-on-the-pentagon-results-in-discovery-of-new-mathematical-tile).